# trying to open a file in loop matlab

Tags: matlab

I have been trying to open files in a loop. I did this:

```
file='';
loc='F:\UT_timestep\';
name='time_';
gridext='.grd';
for i={'a','b','c'}
   file=strcat(loc,name,i,gridext);
   f=fopen(file,'rb');
   ...
   fclose(f);
end
```

but it gives this error :

> Error using fopen
>   First input must be a file name of type char, or a file identifier of type double.
>
> Error in script_UT (line 28)
>       f=fopen(file,'rb');

I am not able to understand why this is giving error. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `file` is a cell array of 1 element.  You want the actual string inside the cell array, not the actual cell itself. Do this:

```
file='';
loc='F:\UT_timestep\';
name='time_';
gridext='.grd';
for i={'a','b','c'}
   file=strcat(loc,name,i,gridext);
   f=fopen(file{1},'rb'); %// Change
   ...
   fclose(f);
end
```